# number format validation rule for laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In validation rule i have regex

```
'amount' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*(\.[0-9]+)*$/|not_in:0',
```

With this, accept ony 1,000,000.00

I need to accept for example all this formats 1000; 10000.00; 10,000.00

for examples:
 1000 accept
 1000.00 accept
 10000000.00 accept
 1000.0000 failed
 1,000.00 accept
 1,000.0000 failed
 1,000,000.00 accept

Comment: What exactly do you want to match? Any number?

Answer (score 1):

Try this regexp(all your numbers in the post will be matched):

```
'amount' => 'required|regex:/^[0-9\.,]+$/|not_in:0'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `numeric` validation, after validate only use [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
'amount' => 'required|numeric|not_in:0',
```

then

```
$amount = number_format($request->get('amount'), 2);
```

Simple, easy to understand